# order by column based on starting Number(Number may be decimal) in a string in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

i have a column named name in my table and example data i have included below

```
name 
-----
1.arun888
2.nikl55555
11.abcd5566
1.123.bhdf
2.767ss777
1.21cdm
```

and i want to sort the deatils like below

```
name
----
1.arun888
1.123.bhdf
1.21cdm
2.nikl55555
2.767ss777
11.abcd5566
```

I have tried many ways but nothing works for me

first method i had used

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100),
 @start int,
 @end int,
 @len int

SET @string = '66555.12tttthe hollies 12345 Test Ad77dress Dr.'
set @string = replace(@string, ' ' , '')
set @len = len(@string)

set @start =  PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@string)

set @end =  PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',substring(@string, @start, @len))-1
print substring(@string, @start, @end)
```

but it gives only 66555
but i need 
66555.12

second method i had used

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

i have used the above function but it wil return all the numbers from string 
example 
if string is  `12.dddh5555`
then it return `125555`

so i am stuck here. i hope somebody can help me to find this

Comment: So your requirements are: sort numerically and any alphabetic characters in decimal part of numbers sort before numbers in decimals?

Comment: The reason this is a problem is because you have violated 1NF by sticking two pieces of data in a single column. Can you separate the data into two columns?

Comment: @xQbert yes  exactly

Comment: @SeanLange i can't do that it is one of our client requirement, we cannot have the provision to change db we can only use an sp to sort this and show in ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( name VARCHAR(20) )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '1.arun888' ),
        ( '2.nikl55555' ),
        ( '11.abcd5566' ),
        ( '1.123.bhdf' ),
        ( '2.767ss777' ),
        ( '1.21cdm' );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   name ,
                        SUBSTRING(name, 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', name) - 1) d
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    ORDER BY CAST(CASE WHEN RIGHT(d, 1) = '.' THEN SUBSTRING(d, 1, LEN(d) - 1)
                       WHEN d = '' THEN '0'
                       ELSE d
                  END AS DECIMAL(30, 10))
```

First I select substrings till the first symbol that is not dot or digit. Then just remove last dot and order by the result.

With function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetNumeric
    (
      @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256)
    )
RETURNS DECIMAL(30, 10)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @s1 VARCHAR(256) = SUBSTRING(@strAlphaNumeric, 1,
                                             PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',
                                                      @strAlphaNumeric) - 1)


        RETURN CAST(CASE WHEN RIGHT(@s1, 1) = '.' THEN SUBSTRING(@s1, 1, LEN(@s1) - 1)
                         WHEN @s1 = '' THEN '0'
                         ELSE @s1
                    END AS DECIMAL(30, 10))
    END
GO

SELECT  * FROM TableName 
ORDER BY dbo.fn_GetNumeric(name)
```

Comment: look like it gives the correct order , can i use this as a function ? then i can use that function directly in sp ?

Comment: and one more thing what will happend if it contains a string ?? like "hai" ??? query will fail ??

Comment: i think the query will fail if one name does not starting with numbers .. right ?can we solve that too ? any suggestions ?

Comment: If  there is no numeric data then I have added to replace that with `0`.

Comment: awesome , really a grate answer , thanks for your support

Comment: Why not turn that into an iTVF instead of a scalar? The performance would be worth it. Just makes the code a bit windy.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i have one more doubt what happends if the string is 11.22.33.44arun ???